# Radius of convergence of multivariate Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, taylor-series

Consider the function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^{l}$ given by \begin{eqnarray}\left(x_{1},...,x_{l}\right)\mapsto\left(\sum_{i=1}^{l}\frac{1}{\left(1+x_{i}\right)^{k_{i}}}-\left(l-1\right)\right)^{-1} \end{eqnarray} where $l\geq1$ and $k_{1},...,k_{l}\in\mathbb{N}$. I claim that the corresponding (multivariate) Taylor series around $x=0$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{l}$ with $\sum_{m=1}^{l}\frac{1}{\left(1+x_{m}\right)^{k_{m}}}>l-1$. At first glance this looks obvious, but (at least for me) it isn't. Does anybody have an idea on how to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_l)$. We can write the function $f(x)$ defined in the question as $f(x) = P(x)/(1 - Q(x))$, where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials and $Q$ has *non-negative* coefficients. Therefore, for $x \in \mathbb{R}_+^l$ such that $Q(x) < 1$, we can expand and rearrange the terms of the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (Q(x))^n$ (and still get a convergent series) to get the Taylor series of $1 / (1 - Q(x))$. Now we multiply this series by $P(x)$, expand and rearrange the terms once again, and we arrive at the Taylor series of $P(x) / (1 - Q(x))$, which therefore converges in the region $\{x \in \mathbb{R}_+^l : Q(x) < 1\}$. But this is precisely the region the original question asks for.